# Filter not applied to a measure

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have two tables.
[image]

I am computing Kaplan Meier. I calculated a field total patients which in essence counts distinct patients who have length  >= current length  in a row. This is DAX:

```
Total Patients m = 
VAR CurrentLength = SELECTEDVALUE(KM[Length])

RETURN
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT(SDP_Patients[RequestNumber]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(SDP_Patients),
        SDP_Patients[Length] >= CurrentLength
    ),
   ALLEXCEPT(SDP_Patients, SDP_Patients[Age Group])
)
```

I first created a column and then a measure. The problem is that I am applying a filter from Age Group and it is not being applied to this measure. Initially I thought that its because I am creating column which is static and later changed it to dynamic. The problem persists. What am I doing wrong?
In KM I calculate length like this: KM = `GENERATESERIES(0,MAX(SDP_Patients[Length]),1)`
Length is simply difference between start and end date in weeks.

Edit:
I changed measure to this and it works. However, Im not sure why

```
Total Patients m = 
VAR CurrentLength = SELECTEDVALUE(KM[Length])
RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        DISTINCTCOUNT(SDP_Patients[RequestNumber]),
        SDP_Patients[Length] >= CurrentLength,
        ALLEXCEPT(SDP_Patients, SDP_Patients[Service])
    )
```

Comment: How is the age group being selected? If it's in a slicer then you're missing a join to the source table. There are a few ways a filter can be applied: one is using a slicer against a related table, another is using some kind of filter inside your measure using CALCULATE() or using an iterator function and filtering the source table. you don't appear to be doing either one.

Comment: @Pieter I place the filter in filter pane in report

Comment: What columns are you joining the two tables on?

Comment: @Pieter length. since its the only thing common between two

Comment: then you need to use ALL() to remove the filter caused by the join.

Comment: ALL doesn't give correct count